# Python Django PDF Flattening of Form Fields

Tags: python, django, pdf, pypdf, pdfrw

I have a project where I need to fill out pre-made PDFs and the most logical solution that comes to mind to accomplish this is to make the pre-made PDFs into PDF forms so there are tags where input values are supposed to go, then I can look through the form tags in the PDF and line them up with a dictionary of values.

I have accomplished this using **PyPDF2**. Overall, I took an image of a web form and then opened Acrobat and created a PDF form based on the fields seen in the image, then used **PyPDF2** for filling out the PDF form fields, but the caveat is that printing those filled in values seems buggy in some browsers, Firefox being one.

How do I got about converting my PDF-Form to a standard/flat PDF so I can keep the pre-populated values, but lose the editable fields (as I think this is the issue)?

```
from io import BytesIO

import PyPDF2
from django.http import HttpResponse

from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject


def pdf_view(request):
    template = 'templates/template.pdf'

    outfile = "templates/test.pdf"

    input_stream = open(template, "rb")
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(input_stream, strict=False)
    if "/AcroForm" in pdf_reader.trailer["/Root"]:
        pdf_reader.trailer["/Root"]["/AcroForm"].update(
            {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})

    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    set_need_appearances_writer(pdf_writer)
    if "/AcroForm" in pdf_writer._root_object:
        # Acro form is form field, set needs appearances to fix printing issues
        pdf_writer._root_object["/AcroForm"].update(
            {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})

    data_dict = {
        'first_name': 'John',
        'last_name': 'Smith',
        'email': 'mail@mail.com',
        'phone': '889-998-9967',
        'company': 'Amazing Inc.',
        'job_title': 'Dev',
        'street': '123 Main Way',
        'city': 'Johannesburg',
        'state': 'New Mexico',
        'zip': 96705,
        'country': 'USA',
        'topic': 'Who cares...'

    }

    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(0))
    pdf_writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(pdf_writer.getPage(0), data_dict)

    output_stream = BytesIO()
    pdf_writer.write(output_stream)

    # print(fill_in_pdf(template, data_dict).getvalue())

    # fill_in_pdf(template, data_dict).getvalue()
    response = HttpResponse(output_stream.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="completed.pdf"'
    input_stream.close()

    return response


def set_need_appearances_writer(writer):
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        # get the AcroForm tree and add "/NeedAppearances attribute
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)})

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)


    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))

    return writer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was super simple, read the docs when in doubt. In this case the Adobe Docs noted that all I needed to do was change the bit position of the field flags to 1, making the field ReadOnly, like so:

```
from io import BytesIO

import PyPDF2
from django.http import HttpResponse

from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject, NumberObject


def pdf(request):
    template = 'templates/template.pdf'

    outfile = "templates/test.pdf"

    input_stream = open(template, "rb")
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(input_stream, strict=False)
    if "/AcroForm" in pdf_reader.trailer["/Root"]:
        pdf_reader.trailer["/Root"]["/AcroForm"].update(
            {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})

    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    set_need_appearances_writer(pdf_writer)
    if "/AcroForm" in pdf_writer._root_object:
        # Acro form is form field, set needs appearances to fix printing issues
        pdf_writer._root_object["/AcroForm"].update(
            {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})

    data_dict = {
        'first_name': 'John\n',
        'last_name': 'Smith\n',
        'email': 'mail@mail.com\n',
        'phone': '889-998-9967\n',
        'company': 'Amazing Inc.\n',
        'job_title': 'Dev\n',
        'street': '123 Main Way\n',
        'city': 'Johannesburg\n',
        'state': 'New Mexico\n',
        'zip': 96705,
        'country': 'USA\n',
        'topic': 'Who cares...\n'

    }

    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(0))
    page = pdf_writer.getPage(0)
    pdf_writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(page, data_dict)
    for j in range(0, len(page['/Annots'])):
        writer_annot = page['/Annots'][j].getObject()
        for field in data_dict:
            # -----------------------------------------------------BOOYAH!
            if writer_annot.get('/T') == field:
                writer_annot.update({
                    NameObject("/Ff"): NumberObject(1)
                })
             # -----------------------------------------------------
    output_stream = BytesIO()
    pdf_writer.write(output_stream)

    response = HttpResponse(output_stream.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="completed.pdf"'
    input_stream.close()

    return response


def set_need_appearances_writer(writer):
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        # get the AcroForm tree and add "/NeedAppearances attribute
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)})

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
      

    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))
    
    return writer
```

Comment: Superb detective work in some thoroughly boring documentation. Do you know if this can be generally applied to all field types? I've currently got checkboxes & text fields & can't disable the check boxes.

Comment: @markwalker_ unfortunately I could not get checkboxes to work the same way as text fields, what I ended up doing in that situation was to create text fields for the "checkboxes" and then I rendered an "X" overtop and flattened it.